# Connection with On-premises PostgreSQL DB from Azure Data Factory specifically in Mapping data flows

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

By using Pay As You Go in Azure, Will I be able to connect to PostgreSQL DB in mapping data flow which is implemented inside azure data factory.

I want to connect to an On-premises postgreSQL DB at source and then transform the data in mapping data flow, once done then again send the transform data back into On-premises PostgreSQL DB. If you see here, the options for PostgreSQL are not active. So does that mean that I need Upgrade to PAY AS YOU GO Subscription.

[Image shows that PostgreSQL cannot be leveraged in ADF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpqmp.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a customer support question around subscription types and billing.

Comment: Actually, I tried asking the Q is Microsoft Tech Community. But there was no reply. I am merely interested in getting the solution. Once I get the solution, I will delete the Q.

Comment: What I'm saying is, subscription types, and payment options, are off-topic things here. That said: You have made a false assertion that "PostgreSQL cannot be leveraged in ADF." This is related to Data Flows, not to ADF as a whole. Try using a Copy activity.

Answer (score 0):

Hey [Pushkar Wani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17286801/pushkar-wani) this seems to be an issue with your Subscription type. Tested the scenario in a paid subscription and I am able to visualize the Databases (not grayed out).

[image]

So,

1. you can try [upgrading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/upgrade-azure-subscription) your subscription to paid version or
2. As rightly suggested by [David Makogon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272109/david-makogon), reach out to support teams via an [Azure Support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request)